# Query for a PhD

Tags: phd, research-process, europe, eu

I have completed my bachelor.I have the following question
1)is it possible in any country of Europe to do a phD without a masters degree?

Comment: Technically, yes, some do; but even then, a masters is expected, except in exceptional cases.

Comment: This highly depends on the country you are interested in - Europe is not a single entity when it comes to universities, despite some efforts being made to make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is often *possible*, but whether it is actually done depends entirely on your field. For example, in biology it may be expected to get your Masters first, while in Psychology it may be common to go directly into your PhD. Often, a university will not accept you without a Masters if it is the common practice in your field.

I'd recommend asking someone you know at your current institution whether people in your field often complete a Masters prior to enrolling in a PhD.